# Search for column values in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I want to find a specific data like Country name 'Spain' or any person name like 'John'

So is there any way to find which table's columns contain data `Spain` or `John` in a SQL Server database (remember these are not column Names, these are values stored in the columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below stored procedure, [I found it here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm).

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
    -- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
    -- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
    -- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
    -- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000
    -- Date modified: 28th July 2002 22:50 GMT


    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this stored procedure and pass the data which you want to find

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[FindMyData_String]    Script Date: 07/04/2012 12:58:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindMyData_String]
    @DataToFind NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ExactMatch BIT = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

    INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
    SELECT  C.Table_Name,C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.Column_Name, C.Data_Type
    FROM    Information_Schema.Columns AS C
            INNER Join Information_Schema.Tables AS T
                ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE   Table_Type = 'Base Table'
            And Data_Type In ('ntext','text','nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char')


DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DataExists BIT
DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @ExactMatch = 1
                            THEN 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       = ''' + @DataToFind + '''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            ELSE 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       Like ''%' + @DataToFind + '%''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            END,
        @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
        @i = 1

SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
FROM   @Temp

WHILE @i <= @MAX
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
        FROM    @Temp
        WHERE   RowId = @i


        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

        IF @DataExists =1
            UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT  SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   DataFound = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t bother with any complex stored procedures as long as I can use some of the free tools that already exist on the market. Just install any of these and you’ll get the job done a lot faster.

[SSMS toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=5) – searches only data. Free for all versions except 2012

[ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx)  – searches objects and data

There is also SQL Search from Red Gate but I never used it myself.